# Keep Getting a error object REGEXP isn't a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using an API to get skins of a ship from a wiki but i keep getting an 
`[object RegExp] is not a function` error.

I've tried using Object.values()

```js
title: `Class`,
            description: `${ship.class}`,
            thumbnail: {
                url: `${ship.skins.filter(/Default/)}`,
            },
```

`(node:5532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: [object RegExp] is not a function
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Ash\Desktop\Discord.js Bot\commands\azurlane\azurship.js:20:36)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:5532) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5532) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Answer (score 1):

```
ship.skins.filter(/Default/) //error here [object RegExp] is not a function
```

you are getting error because filter is a function which take a callback function as its parameter. this callback function accepts 3 parameter : item, index , array

example:

```
var result = [1,2,3].filter((item,index,array)=> item > 1 );
```

here, the callback function return true when item is greater then 1, and we have a filtered array as the value of `result` having value `[2,3]`

Comment: So what i was trying do was to get the skin image ,"skins": [
 ``       { 
            "title": "Default",
            "image": "https://azurlane.koumakan.jp/w/images/thumb/0/06/Akagi.png/600px-Akagi.png"
        },`` I only wanted the default skin so i tried using /Default/ to filter it i don't know how do i do it with this api if i wanted to get the image.

Comment: can you please mention the api url